# How can I set different session lifetime for each role?

Tags: symfony

How can I set different session lifetime for each symfony role? Is there a built-in option for doing this?

We're using different roles, one for our clients and one for each department within our company. We'd like to increase session lifetime for company roles without increasing it for the clients role.

Comment: You really cannot. But it is doable. Can you please update your question with more details/use case?

Comment: @JovanPerovic updated!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set the session lifetime for the role that has the highest, and then, saving dates on your database, log users out after the amount of time that you want.